# Can JSTL be used in HTML page?

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have run JSTL tag on JSP page but could not run the same code on HTML page. So, if its possible can anyone help me on it!

Comment: No. It is not possible to have JSTL in HTML page.

Comment: If you have to.. then you could rename your page from page.html to page.jsp and use JSTL tags in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As name it self indicates

> The JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) is a collection of useful JSP tags which encapsulates core functionality common to many JSP applications.

And if you see the [**wiki of JSTL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages_Standard_Tag_Library)

> It extends the JSP specification by adding a tag library of JSP tags for common tasks,

*Summary*:**You cannot use.**

Answer (score 2):

You can't, they only run on JSP pages. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Not Possible to do this.It supports only JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Any JSP file is recompiled is when the file is modified and the web container detects it, but definitely this is the wrong approach... What about saving HTML templates in the database and process them before JSP receives them?